# Are there published rules for a liquid race in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

Some of the guys at my table are big Futurama fans. They have asked me to put together a homebrew set in the world from the episode "My Three Suns" (in which the native race are a humanoid species but comprised entirely of water).

I am stuck on what racial bonuses and weaknesses to assign such characters. Swim speed seems appropriate, and -2 str/+2 dex, but it still feels lacking. Are there any published resources (third-party acceptable) for Pathfinder races made entirely of liquid?

Comment: What are the key differences between  "My Three Suns" humanoid and a human? What can they do that Fry or Leela can't (and vice-versa)? Don't worry about using Pathfinder terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the region of D&D 3.5e Homebrew, there is the [Slime Child](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Slime_Child_(3.5e_Race)) (LA+2) Race. A modified version of this seems like your most desirable choice. Some highlights:

> -2 Dexterity +4 Constitution, -4 Charisma, +2 Wisdom (could be simplified as +2 Con and Wisdom, -2 ChA)
>
> Partial Ooze Traits: a Slime Child has many of the same traits as ooze creatures, including immunity to sleep effects, a Slime Child eats, but does not sleep and cannot wear heavy armor. But due to their human ancestry they are subject to paralysis, stunning, polymorph effects, and are subject to critical hits and flanking. They are also affected by any spell or effect that could target an Ooze.
>
> Partial Human Traits: Slime Children are affected by all spells and affects that can target a humanoid despite being an Aberration. Its the result of a flaw in their initial creation process.
>
> Slime Core (Ex): The slime child has a vital point and thus is vulnerable to critical hits and precision damage is extremely difficult to hit them and giving them a natural resistance to such attacks in the form of a 75% miss rate for critical hits and precision based damage such as from a sneak attack.
>
> Favored Class: Fighter

---

A third party company, Alluria Publishing, made [Squole](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/3rd-party-races/alluria-publishing/squole/), a sentient Ooze PC race (which would be easy to handwave as liquid). Among other things, they seem to have Blindsight 40ft. If that is an acceptable exchange, you may have to purchase the [sourcebook](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/64312/Remarkable-Races-Compendium-of-Unusual-PC-Races?cPath=4665_4708) because it's not SRD content. There's a Reddit review of it if you want a little more information before investing.

Comment: Huh, I would expect a *constitution* penalty.

Comment: Actually I think bonus makes sense... Constitution is both how physically resillient you are and your ability to resist disease and nausea type effects... It doesn't necessarily mean think skin. Skin that reforms as it gives way is also fairly constituent

Comment: It looks like Slime Child is just a homebrew race. Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess I missed that. I'll note that it's such, although OP seemed to like it