# Can a summon monster type spell be made permanent?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, spellcasting, summoning, permanency

Is there a RAW way to summon a monster of some variety and make it permanent? In my scenario I'm thinking of Oozes specifically, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: The fact that you're thinking of summoning oozes makes a very big difference; many of the spells that can call or summon a creature from another plane (and last indefinitely) only work on outsiders and elementals.

Comment: The spell *permanency* certainly cannot do it, but I don’t know whether or not there’s anything else that can.

Comment: @KRyan Yes and no. It's true that none of the *summon monster* spells are among the spells listed in *permanency*'s spell description as being able to be made permanent, but the *permanancy* spell's description also specifies that at the GM's discretion, it may be possible to research a version of a non-listed spell that can be made permanent. So, while *permanancy* probably can't do it, "probably" is not "certainly."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Not in a straightforward way

There does not appear a clean way to do this. (To be honest, even to *summon* an ooze in the first place seems to be difficult, as oozes are not one of the options of *summon monster*.) Here are a few ways that *might* work, with a lenient DM:

#### Gate

This would only work on an extraplanar ooze, and one that is intelligent to agree to a trade to boot. Not a great selection there. [Gate](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/gate.htm) allows you to call any kind of creature. It says:

> The second effect of the gate spell is to call an extraplanar creature to your aid (a calling effect). By naming a particular being or kind of being as you cast the spell, you cause the gate to open in the immediate vicinity of the desired creature and pull the subject through, willing or unwilling.

To get the called creature to stick around permanently (or at least, for a really long time that approximates permanently), you then need to do this:

> If you choose to exact a longer or more involved form of service from a called creature, you must offer some fair trade in return for that service.

#### Binding

I'm not sure how the two effects interact, but possibly [binding](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/binding.htm) your summoned creature in a hedged prison could keep it from disappearing. It says:

> The subject is transported to or otherwise brought within a confined area from which it cannot wander by any means. The effect is permanent. [...]  A bound extraplanar creature cannot be sent back to its home plane due to *dismissal, banishment*, or a similar effect.

So this would come down to if you treat the expiry of the original summoning as a "similar effect" to dismissal, as it sends the creature back to its home plane when the spell ends. I probably wouldn't.

#### Wish

[Wish](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/wish) is not as powerful as in older or newer versions of the game, but after a list of things that does not include making spells permanent, it still has this language

> You may try to use a wish to produce greater effects than these, but doing so is dangerous. (The wish may pervert your intent into a literal but undesirable fulfillment or only a partial fulfillment.)

So in theory this could work, if the DM plays along.

#### Polymorph any Object

This is not summoning in the sense of calling from a different place, but it is calling forth an Ooze nonetheless. You need a creature of higher intelligence and of the desired size. [Polymorph any object](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/polymorphAnyObject.htm) then can turn it permanently into an Ooze (as you get +5 for same kingdom, +2 for same size, and +2 for lower intelligence, and 9+ is sufficient to create a permanent effect).

#### Get a mundane Ooze

This is not a direct solution to the problem of having a summoned Ooze made permanent, but if your goal is to just have an ooze for your dungeon or keep, a simpler way to get one may be to just capture one and put it there. The good thing about this one is that it is clean-cut by the rules, so needs not a lot of DM buy-in.

For example, you could *baleful polymorph* one into a mouse, pocket it, travel to your place, and dispel the polymorph.

Comment: For that last section, [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/190884/4563) has a lot of stuff about oozes, including numerous ways to command, control them, or summon them (Ooze domain, Slime domain, *ooze puppet*, *engulfing terror*, *wall of ooze*, thrall of Juiblex, spell sovereign).

Comment: @KRyan That is a great compilation for things Ooze-related, thanks for sharing it